# Who's that - this ? Or Who's he - she?

Tags: pronouns, interrogatives

I am trying to learn English and I really appreciate your help. my question is:

What is more common in the native speakers, when u don't know about one person?

WHO'S THIS? - WHO'S THAT?

or

WHO'S SHE? - WHO'S HE?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Both pairs of phrases are perfectly acceptable. Which to choose depends on context. "Who is this" or "Who is that" makes sense when you can refer to the person (perhaps by pointing to them in a photograph, or referring back to something someone just said, though the reference could be implicit, too) whereas "who is he" or "who is she" doesn't require that sort of frame of reference.